# I am using a GCP service account, but when calling Dialog Flow API I get an error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

Here is the error:

> Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the
> Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the
> dialogflow.googleapis.com. We recommend that most server applications
> use service accounts instead. For more information about service
> accounts and how to use them in your application, see
> https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.

Comment: I would double check that your application isn't running using the Application default credentials, and that your machine wasn't configured using 'gcloud auth login' or something similar.

Comment: thanks..!! now it start working i just activate my service account  by using gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file <path to file>.

Comment: @BugResolver Can you please add your solution as an answer in this post? so everyone could see it better. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of the Client Libraries pull from the [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application), a summary of how they're checked is provided on that link. Essentially it will check environmental variables for a path and pull credentials from that location. This error message means you're using a User account, and not a service account.

Most commonly you logged in once using `gcloud auth login`, and even though you provided your service account it's still pulling from the Application Default location.

As you did, the method to associate a specific service account is `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file <path>`

Alternatively to use the true application default you can use `gcloud auth application-default login`

Comment: also i have change code :let config = {
                      credentials: {
                        private_key: privateKey,
                        client_email: clientEmail
                      }
                    }
                    const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient(config);
                    const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);                    
                    }